# Can I cast multiple Battle Magic spells in one 12 strike rank round?

Tags: spells, combat, runequest

I am just starting to play 2nd Edition Runequest after 20 years since I played it last time, and it's all coming back to me. The question I cannot seem to find an answer to is about Battle Magic spells. Can you cast more than 1 spell in a 12 strike rank round if you are quick enough?

***For example, if my Dex Strike Rank is 2 and my spell is a 2 point Bladesharp spell and the focus for my Bladesharp is on the blade of my sword (Ready) I believe it will happen at strike Rank 3 Dex SR + POW -1 (My Focus is ready in my hand). This then leaves me 9 more strike ranks to cast more battle magic?***

So I could in theory cast 4 spells in a 12 strike rank round if they were all no higher than 2 Points of Power and the focus for each was ready.

Does anyone know if this is correct, or have a missed an important paragraph in the rules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Only one spell can be cast per melee round

My copy of *Runequest* (1980) has on its inside front and back covers a list of Second Edition *Runequest* Clarifications, Corrections, and Additions. To be clear, this isn't something *I* printed and shoved into my own book, but, instead, actual—for lack of a better term—errata from the game's publisher that's printed straight onto the book's covers. (Good on the publisher for being responsible and keeping costs down, I guess? I can only imagine the book's price were layout to've been done again *in 1980* so as to incorporate this errata into the main text.)

Anyway, in this errata under the heading Chapter Five under the subheading Page 33 there's this:

> Other Properties of Spells—6. Only one spell may be cast in one melee round unless the caster is under the influence of the Rune magic spell, Multispell. See Chapter Seven [for the Multispell spells' descriptions which start on page 62].

So it appears that you weren't alone in asking this question.

Comment: Fantastic Thanks for the response, I missed that small print :-)